# Undocumented word-break: break-word CSS property?

Tags: css, safari, word-wrap

We want to avoid long words overflowing the line and let them be broken if they have to, for which the standard approach is

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Or its equivalent

```
overflow-wrap: break-word
```

However, we found this not to work on Safari (including Mac and iOS).

We then discovered by accident that the `word-break` CSS property, which is supposed to only accept a value of `break-all`, meaning to break anywhere at all,  apparently takes an undocumented value of `break-word` (Chrome accepts this as well), and that the following

```
word-wrap:  break-word;
word-break: break-word;
```

appears to solve the problem on Safari.

I was unable to find any references on the web either to the non-standard `break-word` value for `word-break`, or to any Safari "bugs" with `word-wrap: break-word` that using `word-break: break-word` would solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know `word-break: break-word;` is non-standard, webkit only. It can be found on [Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-word-break)

> word-break Specifies the level of strictness when breaking lines of
>   text in ideographic languages such as Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.
>
> Syntax word-break: strictness Parameters strictness The level of
>   strictness. Constants break-all, **break-word**, normal Availability
>   Available in Safari 3.0 and later. Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Support Level Stable CSS 3.

Answer (score 3):

`word-break: break-word` is officially deprecated.

From the [CSS Text Module Level 3 Working Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#valdef-word-break-break-word):

> For compatibility with legacy content, the `word-break` property also
>   supports a deprecated `break-word` keyword. When specified, this has the
>   same effect as `word-break: normal` and `overflow-wrap: anywhere`,
>   regardless of the actual value of the overflow-wrap property.

If you like what `word-break: break-word` seems to do (which I do!), you should use `word-break: normal` and `overflow-wrap: anywhere` instead (and then you can try changing each of them further if you like)

Comment: word-break: normal and overflow-wrap: anywhere doesn't work on Safari though